# Row values copied into Variant as String, when using For Each on Rows collection

Tags: excel, vba

I know that it is possible to get all the values from an Excel Range into an array using the `Value` property:

```vb
Dim arr As Variant
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
Debug.Print TypeName(arr)
' prints Variant()
```

However, when I try to iterate over the rows in the range (via the `Rows` property), and similarly assign the `Value` to a `Variant`, I get a text-delimited string:

```vb
Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    arr = row.Value
    Debug.Print TypeName(arr)
    Exit Sub
Next
' prints String
```

Not sure if this is related, but the VBA IDE reports the type of `row` as `Range/Range`, and the type of `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` as `Variant/Object/Range`. `TypeName` in both cases returns `Range`.

Why is this different, and how can I get the first behavior?

(I am aware that I could probably `Split` the string into an array, but I don't want to do this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looping through rows, you are looping through cells.

So, TypeName will return the data type of the value in the first cell.

If you change the code to this then arr will be of type Variant().

```
Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    arr = row.Value
    Debug.Print TypeName(arr)
    Exit Sub
Next
```

Comment: ::facepalm:: (15 characters)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```vb
Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

is the same as:

```vba
Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
```

when maybe you expected this:

```vb
Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows 'need to be explicit about this....
```

The `.Value` of a single-cell range isn't returned as an array

Comment: ::facepalm:: (15 characters)